# I can't figure out what I am doing wrong in the smart contract I am writing. It includes a random mint function with a constructor

Tags: solidity

I'm really new to coding and to the smart contract world so I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thank you very much.

My code is:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "https://github.com/1001-digital/erc721-extensions/blob/main/contracts/RandomlyAssigned.sol";

contract NFT_Test is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable, RandomlyAssigned {
  using Strings for uint256;

  string baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost = 0.003 ether;
  uint256 public currentSupply = 0;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 5000;
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 50;
  bool public paused = true;
  bool public revealed = false;
  string public notRevealedUri;

function RandomlyAssigned(uint256 , uint256 num) {
    for (uint256 a = 1; a <= num; a++) {
        mint(msg.sender, amount);
    }

constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI,
    string memory _initNotRevealedUri
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);
    RandomlyAssigned(5000,200)
  }


  // internal
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseURI;
  }

// public
  function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(!paused);
    require(_mintAmount > 0);
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);
    require(tokenCount() + 1 <= maxSupply(), "YOU CAN'T MINT MORE THAN MAXIMUM SUPPLY");
    require(availableTokenCount() -1 >= 0, "YOU CAN'T MINT MORE THAN AVAILABLE TOKEN COUNT");


    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
      require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
      require(balanceOf(msg.sender) <= 1);
    }

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + i);
    }
```

The error appears here:

```
constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI,
        string memory _initNotRevealedUri
      ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
        setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);
        RandomlyAssigned(5000,200)
      }
```

The error received is:

```
from solidity:
ParserError: Expected primary expression.
    --> contracts/Copy_Dirty_Staffy_NFT.sol:1255:1:
     |
1255 | constructor(
```

I suspect that there may be other errors that I haven't yet gotten to, however, if I remove the Randomly Assigned function completely and keep just the original code written by hashlipz, the contract works with no issues.

Thank you so much to anyone willing to help and apologies I'm a noob.

Comment: Maybe it's the missing `;` at the end of `RandomlyAssigned(5000,200)`. Also there are some missing brackets around the code I think

Comment: it seems like you did not close RandomlyAssigned with "}"

Comment: @0xSanson, I added in the ; but I still have the error. I'm struggling to identify where the missing brackets should go.

Comment: @Yilmaz when I close the RandomlyAssigned with "}", another error appears in the for loop